# How to convert a document to a .str and a .ttml file

Tags: string, file, ttml

I have a document saved in notepad, but for some reason after saving it, it is appears in properties at .str.txt and .ttml.txt instead of just .str or .ttml, which is what I would like it to be.

I think that I tired it all, following tutorials and I'd be glad to know what I am doing wrong, or simply - not doing?

Comment: This is what notepad always does, irritatingly. Go to a command prompt and use the rename command: rename example.str.txt example.str

Comment: Alternatively you can select `All Files (*.*)` as File format, when saving the file

Comment: Thank you very much! That was such an simple solution!! All I had to do was to change it to All Files! And it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: Please post this as an answer, not a comment.